is there a better (?) way to maintain a bidirectional mapping of strings
I've got a use case for what I'll call an "invertible dictionary" -- because I don't know a better term for it.  I've got a set of data where the values for some properties are repeated all over the place... think about a database where there are a million records but they share maybe a few dozen unique values for cities or states or countries or whatever.
The optimization assumes that you have a much smaller number of unique values, and that you're doing lookups on the key string far more often than you're doing inserts or modifications.
What I came up with was what I call a string dictionary, which I hacked up below.  It basically takes a dict, then builds a list of the unique entries so we can use the index of that list to very quickly get the string.  The indirection allows me to store just the index for each record instead of the whole string.
Anyway... this works fine, but it seems like python always has some builtin or well-maintained version of everything I write like this, so I figured I'd ask if such a thing already exists...
class StrMap(dict):
    """ provides a fast mapping of strings to integer indices in a list.
        all keys of type int have values of type str
        all keys of type str have values of type int
        examples: d['ace'] : 0,  d['bob'] : 1, d[0] = 'ace', d[1] = 'bob' and so on
    """    
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.L = []

    def add(self, newval : str) -> int:
        assert isinstance(newval, str)
        if newval not in self:
            newidx = len(self.L)
            self.L.append(newval)
            self[newval] = newidx
            return newidx

    def retr(self, multikey, addOnMiss=True):
        if isinstance(multikey, int):
            return self.L[multikey]
        elif isinstance(multikey, str):
            try:
                return self[multikey]
            except KeyError:
                if addOnMiss:
                    return self.add(multikey)
                else:
                    print(f"addOnMiss is not set and string key {multikey} is not in dict")
                    raise KeyError



Why go through indices instead of simply referencing the string directly?

Do you want to use indices for some reason? What does typical code using your StrMap look like?

To be clear, you are assuming that d[d[x]] == x when x is already a key? (addOnMiss seems strongly asymmetrical, at least outside of any domain-specific usage of StrMap.) I can't tell if you are just trying to implement an ad-hoc interning system or not.

This question is similar to: A data-structure for 1:1 mappings in python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

retr() is weird. Call it get(), or __getitem__()

"The indirection allows me to store just the index for each record instead of the whole string." Have you considered using sys.intern to just intern your strings? That way you don't need to implement your own int->string mapping. Every reference to an interned string will be equal, if the refereed-to strings are equal. So that lets you just pass those references around transparently, without actually having multiple copies of the same text.

I mean, making this a subclass of dict doesn't make sense to me, since every other method subverts your add method, so why expose them at all?

The bidict library provides bidirectional mapping, you can efficiently look up keys by values and vice versa.
from bidict import bidict

my_dict = bidict({'ace': 0, 'bob': 1})

print(my_dict['ace'])      # 0
print(my_dict.inverse[1])  # 'bob'

You can read more about it in the bidict.readthedocs.io
